# Changing a button's text when another button is clicked from another view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, button, textfield, viewcontroller

I have one view controller, `PostJobViewController1`, that contains a button that said "Select one...". When the button is clicked, it brings the user to another view controller, `SelectIndustryViewController`, that has a list of industries for the user to choose. This list is made up of multiple buttons and two text fields that say "other".

I want the words, "Select one..." to change to the words of the button that the user selects in `SelectIndustryViewController`. This is kind of confusing, so I provided screenshots of my storyboard. How can I make the "Select one..." button change when another button is clicked from the other view controller? Also, how can I make the "Select one..." button change when the user types in the "other" text field?

[PostJobViewController1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsP6p.jpg)
[SelectIndustryViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpluM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for this is to use the delegation pattern. If you don't have any knowledge of this I recommend watching Sean Allan Delegation pattern on youtube.